# What is the colon 'operator' doing in this example?

Tags: ruby

I saw this example in an answer elsewhere and with the following it outputs `foobar`:

```
a = :foo

def bar(b)
  :"#{b}bar"
end

c = bar(a)

c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colon isn't an operator inside `bar`, it is simply a `Symbol` literal that uses string interpolation to build the `Symbol`. Some `Symbol`s need to be quoted to avoid syntax issues, for example:

```
:'a+b'
```

You can also use double quotes with this syntax and those quotes behave just like double quotes for strings so they support string interpolation. So this:

```
:"#{b}bar"
```

is equivalent to:

```
"#{b}bar".to_sym
```

or

```
(b.to_s + 'bar').to_sym
```

If you `#inspect` your value you'll get a better idea of what it contains:

```
puts c.inspect
# :foobar
```

Comment: It’s worth it to mention that “it is setting variable as a reference” wording in OP is wrong and confusing.

Comment: @mudasobwa I saw that as a confusing and "not their best ever" use of English so going down that rabbit hole would be a distraction.

Comment: You are right about variable as a reference. I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203911/how-to-pass-by-reference-in-ruby. It is clear that the example, where I took this from, had nothing to do with pass by reference.

Comment: I removed the confusing lines at the end. Thanks for the answer!